# Handle empty response with Spring WebClient in a reactive way

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

Is there a way to react on empty responses in Spring WebClient without checking the http status code? The endpoint from which I get data does return http200 even if an error occurs, which is why I need to check the payload itself. In case of an error it returns empty, in case of success it returns a valid payload which should be mapped into a POJO.

As the payload could only consumed once, is a there a way to handle this in a reactive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `switchIfEmpty` operator to handle empty responses and as an option return error

```
webClient.get()
  .uri("<endpoint>")
  .retrieve()
  .bodyToMono(Response.class)
  .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Error response")));
```